# Describing the relation between two things

Tags: sentence-structure

I wrote:

> We expect, the larger a home's living space is, the higher its price is.

First, I would like to know about the correctness of the sentence and punctuation. I don't know exactly the structure of this sentence. I just feel I have seen such structure, but I'am not sure. In general, what are idiomatic ways to express relationship between two things (Increase, or decrease....)

Comment: I think they are called parallel clauses. However, that we expect part makes me think of something like "we expect a higher price for the buildings with larger living rooms". I mean, to me that "we expect" intro and the rest sound a bit incongruous! As you know, I am a learner though!

Comment: In terms of structure, "is" can be omitted:  "The larger a home, the higher its price".

Comment: Why not use the word "proportion" or "proportional"? The size of a home's space is proportional to its price. --- This is, however, neglecting the structure provided in the OP and is merely a suggestion.

Comment: There shouldn't be a comma after *expect*. The sentence is actually *we expect [that] the larger . . .*, but *that* has been omitted.